# Read Address Book data in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm still new to Swift and working with the Address Book in iOS and it's proving to be a bear.  Specifically, I'm trying to read a contact's "Social Profiles".

For string values like first/last name, this works:

```
let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as String
```

But when I try to do essentially the same thing with the   `kABPersonSocialProfileProperty` property "(a multivalue property of type kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType)", like so:

```
let socialData = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonSocialProfileProperty)
```

I get the error: `'CFString' is not convertible to 'ABPropertyID'`

I'm not clear why it throws this error.

I've read the Apple iOS Developer documentation and it seems that `ABRecordCopyValue` *is* the correct function ("Returns the value of a record property.") ... so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Might someone explain the error and where I should go to property read the Social Profile data for a contact from the Address Book?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing (please excuse the partial snippet, part of a matching function):

```
let socialProfiles: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonSocialProfileProperty).takeRetainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef
for var index:CFIndex = 0; index < ABMultiValueGetCount(socialProfiles); ++index {

    if let socialProfile: AnyObject = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(socialProfiles, index).takeRetainedValue() as? NSDictionary {

        let service = socialProfile["service"] as String
        if service == "Twitter" {

            let username = socialProfile["username"] as String
            if username == paramUsername {
                return (true, person)
            }
        }
    }
}
```